# Lazy Highcharts DateTime formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using lazy Highcharts to implement some json data and when i import that data it reads the date fine, but not the time. I have the date time '2014-08-11T11:30:00+00:00' but high charts reads it as '2014-08-11T00:00:00+00:00'. I've tried `strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")` to match the format, but gives me the error: `undefined method`year' for "11/08/2014 11:30":String`

**Controller**

```
dates = []
temps = []
dt = []

@data['data'].flatten.each do |data|
  dates << data.keys
  temps << data.values
end

dates.flatten.each do |date|
  dt << DateTime.parse(date)
end

@start = dt.first

@graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.series(:type => 'line', :name => 'Temperature', data: temps, pointStart: @start, :pointInterval => 30.minutes )
  f.xAxis [ type: "datetime" ]
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

can you put where are you calling strftime? I think if you do

`dt << DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`

everything should work fine, because the error looks like you're trying to call strftime on a string

Comment: Thanks tegon, I've tried that solution. No luck, think it might have something to do with the 'date time' in the xAxis, but i'm struggling to find any solution within rails.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a little late, but I was able to get proper formatting by using `dateTimeLabelFormats` along with `datetime` type.

```
f.xAxis(type: 'datetime', 
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {second: '%l:%M:%S %p',
                               minute: '%l:%M %p', 
                               hour: '%l:%M %p',
                               day: '%e. %b', week: '%e. %b', 
                               month: '%b \'%y', year: '%Y'})
```

You cannot apply the `strftime` and need to let `Highcharts` handle it with the formatting you specify in `dateTimeLabelFormats`.